# Can PageMethods return XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was playing with some ASP.NET PageMethods, and I tried to simply return XML using this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public static string GetIPLocation(string ip)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("relative xml path"));
    var s = doc.ToString();

    return s;
}
```

The exact same code **actually works with ASMX services**, (removing the `static` modifier though)

But it turns out that I cannot get the XML when using PageMethods, **instead, I'm receiving my page's HTML code.**

Here is my AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<%: this.ResolveClientUrl("~/relative path/GetIPLocation") %>",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8;",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: "{ip:'"+$target.val()+"'}",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log("MSG: %o", msg);
        viewModel.ip1(msg.d.IP);
    },
    error: function (XHResponse, errorMessage, errorCode) {
        console.log("AJAX Error: %o", XHResponse);
    }
});
```

If I change the response to JSON or if I use an ASMX/WCF service instead of my PageMethod, it works like a charm

So are PageMethods incapable of returning XML by design??... If not what am I missing?

#### Edit 1

As commented by @JamieSee, I made this modification, still the same result:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public static XDocument(GetIPLocation(string ip)
{
     return XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("relative xml path"));
}
```

and

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public static XmlDocument(GetIPLocation(string ip)
{
    var x = new XmlDocument();

    x.LoadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("relative xml path"));

    return x;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simply returning the XDocument instead of changing it to a string first?

Comment: I just did and I'm getting the same result, I updated my question

Comment: What do you get if you use application/json instead of application/xml in your contentType for the jQuery call? ContentType describes the format of the information you are sending with your POST. DataType describes what you expect back in the response. A mismatch may produce odd results.

Comment: Have you tried setting  ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json?

Comment: @JamieSee You were right, changing the contentType to json worked (since I was sending json as part of my request). Now I'm sending json and receiving XML. That's the experiment I wanted. Can you post your response as an answer to mark it as accepted

Comment: I converted the comment to an answer as you requested. I'm glad this helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it appears you are sending JSON formatted data, try using `application/json` instead of `application/xml` in your `contentType` for the jQuery call.

- The `contentType` describes the format of the information you are sending
  with your POST.
- The `dataType` describes what you expect back in the response.

A mismatch may produce odd results.